# partial derivatives with resistors

Tags: calculus

Two resistors in an electrical circuit with resistance R1 and R2 are wired in parallel with a constant voltage give an effective resistance of R, where  1/R = 1/R1 + 1/R2
Calculate   ∂R/∂R1 what is the approximate value of ∂R/(∂R1) at R1 = 0 and R2 = 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $\frac{1}{R(R_1,R_2)} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}$, and thus in particular, that
$$
R(R_1,R_2) = \frac{R_1 R_2}{R_1 + R_2}.
$$
Taking the derivative of $R$ with respect to $R_1$ by using the quotient rule then yields
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_1}(R_1,R_2) &= \frac{R_2(R_1 + R_2) - R_1R_2}{(R_1 + R_2)^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\right)^2.
\end{align}
$$
Substituting $R_1 = 0$ then gives that $$\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_1} = 1.$$